# MongoDB: language override unsupported: arabic

Tags: mongodb, full-text-indexing, arabic-support

I am trying to make a text index on a `book` document containing data in multiple languages (Essentially: English, French and Arabic).
In the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/text-search-languages/#text-search-languages) it is said that Arabic is supported, but when I try to create a document with these properties:

```
{
  name: 'بلا اسم'
  author: 'مجهول',
  language: 'arabic'
}
```

I get an error saying:

```
MongoError: language override unsupported: arabic
```

I am using MongoDB v4.0.2 community edition

Comment: not sure, but the linked documentation says "to enable support for these languages, see [Text Search with Basis Technology Rosette Linguistics Platform](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/text-search-with-rlp/)." have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that the Arabic support is only available in the entreprise edition

Answer (score -1):

I contacted RLP some time ago and they said the license didn't exist anymore, and now MongoDB people publish right the same. Check it out :

> ## [Text Search Languages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/text-search-languages/#text-search-languages)
>
> REMOVAL OF SUPPORT FOR RLP
> MongoDB Enterprise no longer supports Text Search with Basis Technology Rosette Linguistics Platform.

Comment: I won't be able to adjust anything ! Thanks for the note anyway.